# How can I solve this limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3x}{x + 4} = 3\,$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I have now $\forall \epsilon > 0\;\exists \delta > 0$, such that $\left|\frac{1}{x + 4}\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{12}$ if $x > \delta$. Now I don't know what I have to do. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you trying to *prove* this (something fitting in real analysis) or are you simply trying to show what the limit is using a basic calculus approach (L'Hospital is what you want)?

Comment: I must realize it for definition epsilon - delta. But I don't know what I have to do...

Comment: Okay I just added two tags to make others more aware of what it is you are after. It may be helpful to share more of your thoughts though.

Comment: If $x>\delta > 0$, then $x+4 > \delta + 4$ and $\frac{1}{x+4} < \frac{1}{\delta + 4}$. For which $\delta$ depending on $\epsilon$ do you have $\frac{1}{\delta + 4} \le \frac{\epsilon}{12}$?

Comment: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/preciselimdirectory/PreciseLimit.html This may help you

Comment: @Simple Nice link (good to keep in mind for the future), but it doesn't seem like the best thing here since that link is all about limits where $x\to a$ when $a$ is a constant as opposed to $x\to\infty$ here.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow Thanks, I didn't notice that the question is about $x\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: If I take $\frac{1}{\delta + 4}$ <= $\frac{\epsilon}{12}$ then $\delta$ => $\frac{12}{\epsilon} - 4$. If $\epsilon$ is enough small, then $\delta$ is negative. I am confuse with it. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: No, if $\epsilon$ is small then $12/\epsilon$ is large. You just need to discuss $\epsilon \ge 3$.

Comment: Large, you have reason, but definition says "for all epsilon > 0".

Comment: You can't take $\delta=\frac{12}{\epsilon} - 4$ for every $\epsilon$ if you want $\delta > 0$. For $\epsilon > 3$ you just have take something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $\delta > 0$ is not important in case $x\to \infty$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Define $\delta = \frac{12}{\min(\epsilon, 2)} - 4 \ge 2$.
Then for every $x > \delta$ we have
$$ \frac{3x}{x+4} - 3 = \frac{12}{x+4} < \frac{12}{\delta + 4} \le \min(\epsilon, 2) \le \epsilon. $$

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite

$$
\frac{3x}{x+4} = \frac{3(x +4) }{x+4} -\frac{12}{x+4} = 3 - \frac{12}{x+4}
$$
and use the fact you already have found.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3x}{x+4}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3x}{x(1+\frac{4}{x})}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3}{1+\frac{4}{x}}=3$$

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to follow your thought and propose the following answer. First choose $\delta_1 = 1$ ,then if $x > 1=\delta_1 \to x+4 > x > 1 > 0 \to 0<\dfrac{1}{x+4} < \dfrac{1}{x}$. Next you want $\dfrac{1}{x} < \dfrac{\epsilon}{12}$, and this corresponds to choosing $\delta_2 = \dfrac{12}{\epsilon} > 0$. Now if you take $\delta = \text{max}(\delta_1,\delta_2) > 0$, then if $x > \delta \to \left|\dfrac{12}{x+4}\right| < \epsilon$, and this proves your claim.